# sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I want to install ns2.35 on Ubuntu 14.04. When I implement this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tcl8.5-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'tcl8.5-dev'
E: Unable to locate package tk8.5-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'tk8.5-dev'
```

What should I do for resolving this problem?

Comment: Those packages exist; check your sources.

Comment: I have downloaded package tcl8.5-dev and package tk8.5-dev but I don't know how can I install them. I am a new user of Ubuntu.

Comment: @lafille you can install `*.deb` files by `sudo dpkg -i file.deb` or `sudo dpkg -i /location/file.deb`

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex: Tcl and Tk are in the `main` pocket in Trusty.

Answer (score 3):

These packages exist and they are available in Ubuntu 14.04, here is the output of your command in my Ubuntu 14.04.4:

```
galoget@hackem:~$ sudo apt install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev
  libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxft-dev libxrender-dev libxss-dev
  tcl8.5 tk8.5 x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  libxcb-doc libxext-doc tcl-tclreadline tcl8.5-doc tk8.5-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev
  libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxext-dev libxft-dev libxrender-dev libxss-dev tcl8.5 tcl8.5-dev tk8.5
  tk8.5-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libfreetype6
1 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 261 not upgraded.
Need to get 8.262 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

A tip, you can search for any package for any release version of Ubuntu in [this website](https://packages.ubuntu.com), and also you can download the files from that site, here are the two packages that you're trying to install:

- [tcl8.5-dev (8.5.15-2ubuntu1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tcl8.5-dev)
- [tk8.5-dev (8.5.15-2ubuntu3)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tk8.5-dev)

Once downloaded the .DEB files, to install them, just follow these steps:

- Assuming the .DEB files are for am64 and are located in `~/Downloads`:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  sudo dpkg -i tcl8.5-dev_8.5.15-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i tk8.5-dev_8.5.15-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
  ```

But I believe you're going to need some dependencies for those 2 packages to be installed correctly and work, you can check the output of my terminal at the beginning.

Comment: I tried to install tcl8.5 and tk8.5. After doing this I received these errors:

Comment: It is a good idea to publish your updates by editing your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add *main* repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
```

And retry installation

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```