# dependencies are not getting installed

Tags: dependencies

i am trying to install pillow and for that purpose i need to run this command for the dependencies ,

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

but it gives me this error:

[image]

would someone help me out ?  my ubuntu OS is  running on raspberry pi installed from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

System details:

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001223/sudo-apt-get-install-tcl8-5-dev-tk8-5-dev

Comment: When sharing information from the command line in a PuTTY session, just copy-paste the contents into your post here directly.  Screenshots of text are not as helpful as the actual text *as* text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can understand your Ubuntu version is 19.10, so it has [`tcl8.6` in the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/eoan/tcl8.6).

So you have to install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev
```

or simplier -

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev
```

---

Also I'd recommend to change TIFF and JPEG package names to the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev libjpeg-dev
```